# Array of C-style strings valid at first, then unreadable

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I've had this problem which is driving me quite mad. I have a class, `ImageLoader`, which given some filenames, will load the images using a library I found on the web for quickly handling TIFF files. The library here is unimportant, as well as the actual loading of images.

The problem is the storing and fetching of filenames. Here is the simplest example containing the root of my problem :

```cpp
class ImageLoader {
  public:
    void askUserFiles();
    void loadImages();
  private:
    char** filenamesToLoad; //< Array of C-style strings for filenames
    std::size_t nbImages; //! Number of images, initialized at 0 and set after user choice
};

void ImageLoader::askUserFiles() {
  // Ask the user for files ...
  this->filenamesToLoad = static_cast<char**>(calloc(numberOfuserFiles, sizeof(char*)));
  this->nbImages = numberOfuserFiles;
  // Copy data inside :
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->nbImages; ++i) {
    this->filenamesToLoad[i] = strdup(userFiles[i].c_str());
  }
}

void ImageLoader::loadImages() {
  std::cerr << "Filenames (" << this->nbImages << ") : " << '\n';
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->nbImages; ++i) {
    // Here, printing filenames DOESN'T cause a segfault :
    std::cerr << '\t' << this->filenamesToLoad[i] << '\n';
  }

  // Even in my code, there is nothing here : I print the filenames and process them directly after

  std::size_t currentItem = 0;
  while (currentItem < this->nbImages) {
    // Here, printing filenames DOES cause a segfault, and only when currentItem > 0 :
    std::cerr << '\t' << this->filenamesToLoad[currentItem] << '\n';
    // (It works for the first item in the array, but not the rest)

    // The program doesn't even get this far :
    LibraryFileHandle* f = LibraryOpenFile(this->filenamesToLoad[currentItem]);
    // Note : the LibraryOpenFile takes a const char* as argument, and I'm giving it a char*
    currentItem++;
  }
}
```

The second loop (`while`) is here because at first, this code was the code for a worker thread, supposed to load images (since I need to load a lot of them at once). But now, I'm doing it sequentially, on one core only to determine the root cause of the problem.

I have determined this is not a problem due to `currentItem`, it is always within the boundaries [0, nbImages[, and even the memory segments are the same ! If `filenamesToLoad[0]` is accessed at `0xXXXXXXXXe640` in the first for loop, it will still be accessed at `0xXXXXXXXXe640` in the while loop. But somehow, the memory location is not valid anymore.

It has bugged me since yesterday morning, and I've not been able to resolve it and gone onto other things, but I still need to solve it in the near future.

Does anyone have any idea why this behaviour might be happening ? There is no multi threading at work here, not anymore : this is all single-threaded.

Comment: *I've had this problem which is driving me quite mad* -- Well if you simply used `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char **`, and `std::string` instead of `char *`, maybe some of that madness would go away?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and turn your `char**` into a `std::vector<std:string>`.  The only reason not to do so is if you need to use a legacy C API that needs a `char**`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: And then you should still use a `std::vector<std::string>` plus a `std::vector<char*>` loaded with the addresses of each string's content.  No `calloc`, no `strdup`.

Comment: The hilarious part, to me, is where you are explicitly converting a `std::string` to a C-string.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, good idea.

Comment: The other parts of my project do indeed need some good old arrays of char*, so I'm afraid I cannot just use `std::vector<std::string>` unfortunately

Comment: You can still use `std::string` and vectors.  All you have to do is at the last moment you need to create a char array, simply call the `std::string::c_str()` function.  Bottom line is that just because the underlying API or codebase you're using uses char arrays doesn't mean you have to blindly follow suit -- just provide the functions that require a `char *` the `c_str()`, or at the worse, `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: `vector<char const*> vp; for (auto const& s : v) vp.push_back(s.c_str()); char const** old = vp.data();`.  The array is stable until v or any of the strings in v are perturbed.

Comment: Please post the code of LibraryOpenFile